# A calculation method of directional derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $D_\mathbf vf(\mathbf x) =  \lim_{t\to 0} {f(\mathbf x + t \mathbf v) -f(\mathbf x) \over t} $ be the directional derivative of f in the point $\mathbf x$ and direction $\mathbf  v$, let $ \varphi(t)= f(\mathbf x +t \mathbf v) $ then $ \varphi'(0) = D_\mathbf vf(\mathbf x) $.
I read it on a text book but I don't understand why this statement is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition of derivative:

$$\varphi '(0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac1t (\varphi(0 + t) - \varphi(0)) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac1t (\varphi(t) - \varphi(0))$$